# component name not showing up in url

Tags: node.js, vue.js, components, vue-router, router

I am currently building a vue/node app. In my Login.vue page, I use router.push to move to the home page once authentication is done.

Demonstration:

```
router.push({name: 'home', params: {data: this.var}});
```

However, when I do this, it works fine and the functionality is there. However, the url shows `http://localhost:6969:/` instead of `http://localhost:6969:/home`.

How can I do this?

Here is my router:

```
import Vue from "vue";

import Router from "vue-router";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: () => import("./components/Login")
    },
    {
      path: "/home/:data",
      name: "home",
      component: () => import("./components/Home")
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: `home` should be in the URL based on your `path` route config. Can you link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a basic sample application and was able to replicate the behavior you are seeing.

When the variable that I passed in route params existed, the address bar shows the path, but when the variable that I passed in route params was 'undefined', the navigation still changed, but the address bar does NOT show the path.

Not sure if this is what is causing your problem, but I recommend confirming that your '{ data: this.var }' value is defined.

Here is my code.

Router:
NOTE: Normally I would include 'props: true' in my route object, but left it out to match your example.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

import Home from '@/components/stackoverflow/router-props/Home'
import RouterProps from '@/components/stackoverflow/router-props/RouterProps'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/routerprops/:id',
    name: 'routerProps',
    component: RouterProps,
    // props: true
  }
]

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})
```

Home.vue (NOT the route with parameter in my test):

NOTE: See method 'goRouterProps' for the two scenarios.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <h3>Home.vue</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <router-link class="btn btn-primary" :to="{ name: 'routerProps', params: { id: this.id }}">RouterProps via link</router-link>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @click="goRouterProps">RouteProps via push</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        id: 1
      }
    },
    methods: {
      goRouterProps() {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'routerProps', params: { id: undefined }})
        //this.$router.push({ name: 'routerProps', params: { id: this.id }})
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And RouterProps.vue, which is navigated to:

```
<template>
  <div class="router-props">
    <h3>RouterProps.vue</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <router-link class="btn btn-primary" :to="{ name: 'home'}">Home</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    // props: {
    //   id: {
    //     type: Number,
    //     required: true
    //   }
    // }
  }
</script>
```